# Reading from a .txt file and printing in a table form

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabular

So how can I manipulate a piece of code so that it reads from a .txt file and prints the data in a table format with headings such as 'Resident Number' 'Rent date' 'Price' etc.? The name of the file is Residents.txt

So far, I have this

```
file = open('Residents.txt','r')
For line in file:
    SplitFile = line.split (',')
```

This is the .txt file-
R1,21/09/2015,C1,440,P,0
R2,21/09/2015,C3,290,A,290
R3,21/09/2015,C4,730,N,0
R4,22/09/2015,C5,180,A,180
R5,22/09/2015,C6,815,A,400
R6,23/09/2015,C7,970,N,0
R7,23/09/2015,C8,1050,P,0
R8,23/09/2015,C9,370,A,200
R9,25/09/2015,C10,480,A,250
R10,25/09/2015,C11,330,A,330

This is the representation of each column in the .txt file-

```
line.split[0] = Resident Number      
line.split[1] = Rent Date       
line.split[2] = Customer number        
line.split[3] = Rent amount         
line.split[4] = (A means Accepted)(N means not accepted)(P means Pending)          
line.split[5] = Amount paid
```

PLEASE NOTE-
if amount paid equals to rent amount, that residents data shouldn't be shown in the table
if status is N or P, that residents data should also not be shown in the table

How can I display a table (WITHOUT importing modules) which has headings of 'Resident number' 'Rent date' 'Customer number' 'Rent amount' 'Amount outstanding'- amount outstanding is just rent amount - amount paid from that line. Also, how can I print a ultimate total of the outstanding amount of money (combined total for everyone that is yet to pay with a status of 'A')

Python 3.5

Thanks

EDIT

```
for i, word in enumerate(line):
        if i == 4 :  # We don't print the status
            continue
        elif i == 2:
            continue
        print(word.ljust(len(headers[i - (i > 4)(i > 2)])), end="    " * ((i - (i > 4)(i > 2)) != len(headers) - 1))
print()
```

FURTHER EDIT (15/02)

```
line = line.strip().split(",")
    subtotal = int(line[3]) - int(line[5])
    line.append(str(subtotal))
    if line[5] == line[3] or line[4] in ("N", "E"):
        continue
    total += subtotal
```

Comment: You mean a table in memory?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: Do you want to store it in a table-like structure in memory, or do you want to simply print it out in a tabular format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
headers = ["Resident Number", "Rent Date", "Customer number", "Rent ammount", "Ammount paid", "Outstanding Ammount"]

print("    ".join(headers))
for line in open("test.txt", "r"):
    line = line.strip().split(",")
    line.append(str(int(line[3]) - int(line[5])))
    if line[5] == line[3] or line[4] in ("N", "P"):
        continue
    for i, word in enumerate(line):
        if i == 4:
            continue
        print(word.ljust(len(headers[i - (i > 4)])), end="    " * ((i - (i > 4)) != len(headers) - 1))
    print()
```

Output:

```
Resident Number    Rent Date    Customer number    Rent ammount    Ammount paid    Outstanding Ammount
R5                 22/09/2015    C6                 815             400             415                
R8                 23/09/2015    C9                 370             200             170                
R9                 25/09/2015    C10                480             250             230
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I make it so that when it prints the table, it is much more neater? As in everything under a header is in line and is under the right header

Comment: If you have a wide enough terminal, it should do that already.  See my updated answer for the output.  That result was from an 80-character-wide terminal.

Comment: Rent amount and Amount paid seem to have the valuse not in line and also, how can I make everything shift to the left so it is in line with the first letter of that column

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't know how to put them in line; it doesn't make sense to me why they aren't.  I have updated my answer to make it left-justified, though.

Comment: How can I add a column which shows the outstanding amount (which is line.split[3] - line.split[5]

Comment: You would have to put the title in the `headers` list, and if you are using the `for` loop, (rather than list-comprehension), right after `line = line.strip().split()`, say `line.append(line[3] - line[5])`.  If you want it somewhere else, you can use the `list.insert()` method.  Note, the title has to be in the right place within the `headers` list.  If you would rather use list-comprehension, I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: line.append(line[3] - line[5])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Try `line.append(str(int(line[3]) - int(line[5]))`

Comment: One final thng, How do i left-justify the outstanding amount, right now it sits in the middle, in no mans land

Comment: Change the `print(word.ljust(...), end=...)` line to `print(word.ljust(len(headers[i - (i > 4)])), end="    " * ((i - (i > 4)) != len(headers) - 1))`

Comment: print(word.ljust(len(headers[i - (i > 4)])), end="  " * (i - (i > 4) != len(headers) - 1))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you remember to add the title to the `headers` list?

Comment: I can't explain it; it works on my computer.  I just edited my answer with the full code, so you could see if there is something different.

Comment: I will edit my initial code, please see if you can find the error

Comment: The problem is that you are also skipping the third column.  If you really want that, change the occurrences of `i - (i > 4)` to `i - (i > 2) - (i > 4)` and remove that title from the `headers` list.

Comment: So I have the amount outstanding on the farthest column, so how can I display the TOTAL outstanding of everyone added together. So the total outstanding from everyone with a status of A

Comment: For every column that you want to add, put the title in the `headers` list, and then in the `for` loop put the right value into the line.  For every column in the file that you want to skip, add a line in the for loop that says `if i == whatever_position: continue`, and add another `i > whatever_position` to all the rest.

Comment: So how would I add up the oustanding amount from everyone with A as their status?

Comment: I'm sorry; I misunderstood.  You can put above your outer `for` loop a line that says `total = 0`.  When you say `line.append(str(int(line[3]) - int(line[5])))`, change it to `subtotal = int(line[3]) - int(line[5])    line.append(str(subtotal))`.  This way, after your check to make sure this line is valid, (after the `if line[5] == line[3] or line[4] in ("N", "P"): continue` lines), you can say `total += subtotal`. By the end of your outer `for` loop, `total` should have the correct value.

Comment: How can I put the total outstanding in line with the final header?

Comment: `print("%*d" % sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4, total)`

Comment: print("%*d" % sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4, total)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Try this: `print("%*d" % (sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4, total))`

Comment: How would I use print("%*d" % (sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4, total)) to put 'TOTAL OUTSTANDING' in the column on the left of the total outstanding

Comment: `print("TOTAL OUTSTANDING%*d" % (sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4 - len("TOTAL OUTSTANDING"), total))` should do it.  You should probably set a variable that has the string "TOTAL OUT..." in it and use that instead.

Comment: How would I Left justify that?

Comment: The "TOTAL OUTSTANDING" string should already be left-justified.  If you want the total itself to be left-justifed, use `print("TOTAL OUTSTANDING: %d" % total`.

Comment: print("TOTAL OUTSTANDING: %d" % total(sum(len(header) + 4 for header in headers) - 4 - len("TOTAL OUTSTANDING"), total))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: It looks like you merged my last two solutions.  My first, (right before your "How would I Left justify that?" comment), puts "TOTAL OUTSTANDING" at the left, and it puts the total on the right.  My second solution puts them both on the left.

Comment: How do I put TOTAL OUTSTANDING under column 4 and the numerical value under column 5? Both left justified, Thank you!

Comment: Since `TOTAL OUTSTANDING` has more characters than `Ammount paid`, you will find your total doesn't quite line up with the other numbers because if it *did* line up, it would squash into the title.  If you change the name of the `Ammount paid` column to something longer or change `TOTAL OUTSTANDING` to something shorter, it should line up better, but I did it in three lines: `title = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING"`  `print((" " * (sum(len(headers[i]) for i in range(3)) + 12)) + title, end="")`  `print("%*d" % (max(len(str(total)) + 1, len(headers[3]) - len(title) + 5 + len(str(total))), total))`

Comment: I just noticed that you unaccepted my answer.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Oh no sorry, My bad I never realised :O

Comment: That's okay.  I just wanted to make sure I hadn't offended you or something. :)  Is everything working?

Comment: Do you know that you marked YoavGlazner's answer as correct?  I won't be offended if that's what you meant; I just don't think it was.

Answer (score -1):

You may use tabulate

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate

from the link:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
        ["Moon",1737,73.5],["Mars",3390,641.85]]
print tabulate(table)
```

output:

```
-----  ------  -------------
Sun    696000     1.9891e+09
Earth    6371  5973.6
Moon     1737    73.5
Mars     3390   641.85
-----  ------  -------------
```

Comment: I cannot use Tabulate as the client does not have the module and is not willing to get it.